# Error MSB4044 - Getting this error when building Xamarin android project

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, msbuild

Error MSB4044: The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task was not given a value for the required parameter "DesignTimeBuild"-  From visual studio for Mac

Tried cleaning the project and and removed all the obj files.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I replaced the file with another in the Android.coomon.targets, this error was fixed and the project got build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your Project and Build individual Components like right click on your common/Droid/iOs individually and click build,instead of doing build all,see if this works

Comment: I tried that already Problem is only for driod project not for IOS.

Comment: did you try building the Droid project individually ?

Comment: Yea tried that as well, only when building android project, causing this error.

Comment: Sorry no clue then,i get this error a lot of times and the method you've mentioned usually solves or using the method that i've mentioned

Answer (score 0):

1.) Check in your `Build` - `Configuration manager` that iOS project is not selected while Droid project is being build.

Or

2.) Check the packages version that you have installed are compatible, i.e `Xamarin.Forms` package version should be compatible with Droid other packages and version should be same for your PCL project.

Hope this may solve your issue.